# shiny htmlOutput doesn't react on second input change

Tags: r, shiny

I have shinyapp to generate google word tree visualisation.
shinyapp interface has two inputs. text and term. 
I subset data.frame for selected text and replace required content in html template.

Template is here https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/wordtree

The problem is, shinyapp changes only once. When I change text or term second time, html page goes white. When I check file on folder, I see that html file content changes but It doesn't show up on shiny page.

**app.R**

```
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
      column(width = 6,  selectInput("input.filter", label = "selec text", choices = mytexts$yazi.header, selected = "text 1")) ,
      column(width = 6,textInput("input.term", "type term", "today"))
      ),
    fluidRow(tags$head(titlePanel("title panel"))),
    fluidRow(htmlOutput("treehtml")) 
  ) ,
server = function(input, output, session) { 
  output$treehtml <- reactive({
    print(input$input.filter)
    print(input$input.term)
    xid <- subset(mytexts, yazi.header == if(is.null(input$input.filter)) {"text 1"} 
                  else {input$input.filter} ) 
    print(xid$L1)
    xxwt <- mytexts.cumle[mytexts.cumle$cumleid == xid$L1, ]
    xxwt <- paste("['", paste(xxwt$clean, collapse = "'], ['"), "'],", sep = "")
    wttemp <- paste(readLines("wordtree/_wordtree_tmp.html"), collapse="\n")
    wttemp <- gsub("today",input$input.term, wttemp, fixed = TRUE)
    wttemp <- gsub("['DEMO1 DEMO2 DEMO3'],",xxwt, wttemp, fixed = TRUE)
    write(wttemp, "wordtree/wttemp.html")
    wttemp
    })
})
```

**wordtree/_wordtree_tmp.html**

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {packages:['wordtree']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(
        [ ['DEMO DEMO DEMO'], ]
      );

      var options = {
        wordtree: {
          format: 'implicit',
          type: 'double',
          word: 'today'
        }
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.WordTree(document.getElementById('wordtree_basic'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
      <div id="wordtree_basic" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just a comment: I don't know whether this is the cause, but you should avoid dots in input id's (like `input.term`).

Comment: thanks, I didn't heard that before. I tried, but it didn't work.

Comment: You don't provide the dataframes `mytexts` and `mytexts.cumle` in your post. So we can't reproduce. And `_wordtree_tmp.html` is a "full" html file, with `html`, `head` and `body` tags. Your app puts this html inside a `div` and is supposed to render this html. I'm not an expert in html but I would be surprised if this is possible to do that.

Comment: And this is not a serious way to render this graph anyway... I'll show you how to that cleanly, but it requires a bit of time.

Comment: Also, you might be interested in this R package (search "diagonalNetwork" in the page) https://christophergandrud.github.io/networkD3/

Comment: (but please provide your dataframes if you expect an explanation of the problem you get)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do as follows for example, using the function `runjs` of `shinyjs`.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(jsonlite)

sentences <- data.frame(
  group = c("A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B"),
  sentence = c("Phrases", "cats are better than dogs", "cats eat kibble", 
               "cats are better than hamsters", "cats are awesome", "cats are people too", 
               "cats eat mice", "cats meowing", "cats in the cradle", "cats eat mice", 
               "cats in the cradle lyrics", "cats eat kibble", "cats for adoption", 
               "cats are family", "cats eat mice", "cats are better than kittens", 
               "cats are evil", "cats are weird", "cats eat mice"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)    

drawChart <- function(sentences, word){
  sprintf("google.charts.load('current', {packages:['wordtree']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(
          %s
  );

  var options = {
    wordtree: {
      format: 'implicit',
      word: '%s'
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.WordTree(document.getElementById('wordtree_basic'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
", toJSON(sentences), word)
}

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    tags$head(
      tags$script(src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js")
    ),
    useShinyjs(),
    fluidRow(
      column(width=6, 
        selectInput("filter", label="select group", choices=c("A","B"), selected="A", selectize=FALSE)
      ),
      column(width=6, 
        textInput("word", "type word", "cats")
      )
    ),
    fluidRow(tags$head(titlePanel("title panel"))),
    fluidRow(tags$div(id="wordtree_basic", style="width: 900px; height: 500px;")) 
  ),

  server = function(input, output, session) { 
    observe({
      dat <- subset(sentences, group==input$filter)$sentence
      sentences <- array(dat, dim=c(length(dat),1))
      runjs(drawChart(sentences, input$word))
    })
  }
)
```

[image]

[image]